# EF6 "Foreign Key Constraint Violation" When Primary Key Value Exists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm following through the Plural Sight Courses for EF6. (I know, I know. I'm slow. Sue me.)

I have a `Clans` table prepopulated with the following value:

```
ID    Name
--    --------------
1     Vermont Ninjas
```

`ID` is the primary key column. Similarly, I have a `Ninjas` table with `ClanId` as a foreign key into the `Clans` table. In my application, I have the following code:

```
private static void InsertNinja()
{
    var ninja = new Ninja
                    {
                        Name = "JulieSan",
                        ServedInOniwaban = false,
                        DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1),
                        ClanId = 1
                    };
    using (var context = new Db())
    {
        context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
        context.Ninjas.Add(ninja);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

However, the call to `context.SaveChanges()` fails with the vague message, "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." Three inner exceptions later, and the following message appears:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Ninjas_dbo.Clans_ClanId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "NinjaDomain.DataModel.Db", table "dbo.Clans", column 'Id'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

Clearly, the value `1` exists in the database. Why is this error occurring, and how do I fix it?

---

As requested:

```
namespace NinjaDomain.Classes
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Ninja
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool ServedInOniwaban { get; set; }
        public Clan Clan { get; set; }
        public int ClanId { get; set; }
        public List<NinjaEquipment> EquipmentOwned { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clan
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClanName { get; set; }
        public List<Ninja> Ninjas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

The `app.config` file contains the following information:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Server Explorer shows that I have two `localdb` instances:

- `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` (where the clan with ID 1 exists)
- `(localdb)\ProjectsV13` (where no tables exist)

It appears that the tables were created in `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`, but it is trying to retrieve the data from `(localdb)\ProjectsV13`.

Do I just need to re-run the `update-database` command to create the database in the right local database?

Comment: The answer here is obvious gentleman. The ninja in question does not actually belong to that clan. I suspect a spy

Comment: With ef you normally have a clan object in your ninja class and then tell with foreignkey attribute that this is linked to ClanId..

Comment: What is the Clans structure. You are missed to create primary key entry in the parent class or made the foreign key unique

Comment: We need to see the entity model in question (`Ninja` and `Clan` classes along with fluent configuration if any).

Comment: @IvanStoev The question has been updated with the class information. There is no fluent configuration involved.

Comment: @NiranjanKala The entity models are POCOs, transcribed directly from the video (where it works correctly). I have no doubt I've done something wrong. But the classes have been added to the question to help facilitate resolution.

Comment: Try getting the `Clan` entity w/ `Id` of `1` from the database to verify it does indeed exist - perhaps you are not connecting to the database you think you are?

Comment: @Moho Tested. It does.

Comment: Check table `Ninja`'s FK's - is there a `Clan_Id` column?  I don't remember if EF6 will automatically hook up your `ClanId` as the FK property to `Clan.Id` but I know if the PK property for `Clan` was `ClanId` it would.

Comment: Using SSMS are you able to insert the record without errors? If you can then the database is correct and there is something going on with EF.

Comment: @RobotOptimist The problem, as I've been able to figure out so far, is that the migration scripts are creating the tables on one localdb instance, but the program is pulling from another localdb instance. I do not know why, or how to fix it.

Comment: You can try get the clan then add new ninja to the clan. `var clan = Context.Clans.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault()` then `clan.Ninjas.Add(ninja)` and finally `Context.SaveChanges()`. If the clan does not exist sure, you are not connecting to the rigth database.

Comment: Maybe you can force to EF use `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` with `<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>`

Comment: @JesusPocoata That is exactly how it's configured, and it's still not using the right database.